# Ordering a bar graph by only one level of a factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data look like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     Dog   3
A     Cat   5
A     Hat   6
B     Dog   8
B     Cat   3
B     Hat   4
```

Col1 and Col2 are factors, and A is the first level of Col1.

I want to plot Col2 as a bar graph in descending order by Col3 but where the order of Col2 within the level of the factor defined as A in Col1 takes precedence. That is, I want the data to be graphed as follows (I have flipped the axes so that the values in Col2 are on the y axis, so the bars of the graph would be read from top to bottom):

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     Hat   6
B     Hat   4
A     Cat   5
B     Cat   3
A     Dog   3
B     Dog   8
```

Right now, I can only get ggplot to display the bars as defined by the largest overall value (8) rather than the largest value within factor level A only (6). So it looks like:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     Dog   3
B     Dog   8
A     Hat   6
B     Hat   4
A     Cat   5
B     Cat   3
```

I know I can do this manually by re-specifying the levels of the factor in Col2, but my real data have 40 values for Col2, so it would take a lot of typing. I have ordered and cut down the data frame using `arrange(Col1, desc(Col3)) %>% select(Col2)` to get a vector that contains the correct ordering of Col2 (`right_order = "Hat", "Hat", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog"`), but I cannot figure out how to use this vector to tell ggplot how to arrange the data. I tried using it in `reorder` but received the error `arguments must have the same length`. I have read innumerable questions and tutorials on reordering factor levels for graphing in ggplot, but I cannot find guidance on how to just use the order within one level of the factor (A in Col1) to arrange the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `arrange` after converting to `factor` with the custom order

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(Col1, desc(Col3)) %>% 
    mutate(Col2 = factor(Col2, levels = unique(Col2))) %>% 
    arrange(Col2, Col1, desc(Col3))
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    A  Hat    6
#2    B  Hat    4
#3    A  Cat    5
#4    B  Cat    3
#5    A  Dog    3
#6    B  Dog    8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Col2 = c("Dog", 
"Cat", "Hat", "Dog", "Cat", "Hat"), Col3 = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: My data have 160 values of the original factor variable, which are recoded into 40 levels of Col2 (repeated for each level of Col1) after calculating pairwise sums of Col3. So it's not immediately apparent from the original data which of the values in Col3 (and thus the levels of Col2) will end up being the largest. Even once I can inspect the order of the 40 levels of Col2 within the single level of Col1, I would like to avoid manually reordering the levels of the factors in Col2 and use the vector with the correct order (generated from arrange(Col1, desc(Col3)) %>% select(Col2)) instead.

Comment: @KellanBaker this is not manually ordering.  We are first arranging based on 'Col1' and descending order of Col3, to change the levels of 'Col2' and then do the `arrange` again

Answer (score 0):

You nearly have the answer (as does @akrun), but I think taking it stepwise is key here.  Generally, the approach is the same.  First, plot your data (`df1`):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Col2, Col3)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Then do the arrangement as you specify, noting that the output is a `data.frame` object, called `d`.  We then map the `unique()` values of that column (`d$Col2`) to refactor `d1$Col2`:

```
d <- df1 %>% arrange(Col1, desc(Col3)) %>% select(Col2)  # returns a dataframe!
df1$Col2 <- factor(df1$Col2, levels=unique(d$Col2))  # unique values of d$Col2 set to levels of df1$Col2 factor
```

Then you can plot again and see the columns are reordered:

[image]

I think the issue with @akrun's approach was that it did not work to do the factoring in the pipe commands.  Take it stepwise: (1) arrange, (2) get your unique ordering from that, (3) refactor.